# Integration over the normal pdf using the change of variable technique

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

I am trying to understand how to integrate normal pdfs and it is proving a bit of a challenge. I think the challenge is more on the mathematical bit of integration. I have the following standard normal pdf and am trying to get $P(-2<x<2)$:

$$f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}2}$$

From [this MIT opencourseware tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWOGfzC3IeY), I am supposed to use the change of variable technique and transform my coordinates from cartesian to polar in order to integrate the function.

Introducing $y$ and integrating over the region $-2<x<2$ and $-2<y<2$:

$$I^2=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\iint e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}2} \, \mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

Transforming to polar coordinates and integrating over the region $0<r<\sqrt8$ and $\frac\pi4<\theta<\frac{7\pi}4$:

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\iint re^{-\frac{r^2}2}\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta$$

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\frac{3\pi}2re^{-\frac{r^2}2} \, \mathrm dr$$

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\frac{3\pi}2\left(e^{-4}-1\right)\approx-1.8455$$

Just from this output, I can already tell that I have made a mistake somewhere since the yielded value is negative. I am hence confused on how to integrate using the change of variable technique. Some bit of insight would be highly appreciated on solving the above problem. Also, is there a simpler way of integrating over the normal cdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the method advertised in the video won't work for a finite interval. Let

$$I=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-2}^2e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\,\mathrm dx$$

Squaring $I$ and introducing another dummy variable $y$ lets us write

$$I^2=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-2}^2\int_{-2}^2e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

The domain of integration is the rectangle $[-2,2]\times[-2,2]$ (denoted by $R$), which can be expressed in polar coordinates as the union of $4$ component triangular regions $T_1,\ldots,T_4$:

$$T_1=\left\{(r,\theta) \mid 0\le r\le2\sec\theta\text{ and }-\frac\pi4\le\theta\le\frac\pi4 \right\}$$

$$T_2=\left\{(r,\theta) \mid 0\le r\le2\csc\theta\text{ and }\frac\pi4\le\theta\le\frac{3\pi}4 \right\}$$

$$T_3=\left\{(r,\theta) \mid -2\sec\theta\le r\le0\text{ and }\frac{3\pi}4\le\theta\le\frac{5\pi}4 \right\}$$

$$T_4=\left\{(r,\theta) \mid -2\csc\theta\le r\le0\text{ and }\frac{5\pi}4\le\theta\le\frac{7\pi}4 \right\}$$

For instance, the integral over $T_1$ would be

$$\frac1{2\pi}\iint_{T_1}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi4}\int_0^{2\sec\theta}re^{-\frac{r^2}2}\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi4}\left(1-e^{-2\sec^2\theta}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta$$

but this cannot be resolved using elementary methods. It has an approximate value of $0.227767$, and incidentally so do the integrals over the other $3$ regions, giving a total of approximately $0.91107$, and hence $I\approx0.9545$.

The reason the method *does* work for integrating $f(x)$ over $\mathbb R$ is that the infinite plane $\mathbb R^2$, i.e.

$$\{(x,y)\mid-\infty<x<\infty\text{ and }-\infty<y<\infty\}$$

remains an infinite plane after converting to polar coordinates to

$$\{(r,\theta)\mid 0\le r<\infty\text{ and } 0\le\theta\le2\pi\}$$

and the limits of integration in polar coordinates are "nice" in the sense that the resulting integral is trivial, whereas a finite square centered at the origin has to get chopped up into $4$ regions with the limits on $r$ depending on $\theta$.